# How to properly read a file in a specific encoding, in Qt?

Tags: qt

I don't understand what happens when I create a text stream and then do setCodec("some_encoding"), does it start assuming that the file I'm reading from is in some_encoding and when I do QTextStream::readAll return me a QString in some_encoding? Or does QTextStream::readAll return a QString in unicode?

Here's what I do:

```
QString read(const char* encoding)
{
  QTextStream stream(&file);
  stream.setCodec(encoding);
  return stream.readAll();
}
```

But I don't get a unicode string back. So, bottom line is, I want to know, how, having a file in some encoding, do I save all the contents as Unicode into a QString? If readAll() returns a string in the encoding specified, how do I convert that QString from that encoding to unicode?

Comment: `QTextStream::readAll` returns a `QString`, which is UTF-16. It's unclear what you mean by "I don't get a unicode string back". Do you mean, the string has wrong chars/wrong length/something, because it was converted to UTF-16 using wrong codec?

Comment: @hyde I explained in my answer. I thought it was wrong, because I wasn't reading from the beginning, I was outputting it to qDebug() and the output was empty, this usually happens to me when the encoding is off. I'm new to encodings, so I didn't know that readAll would return a string in UTF-16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this didn't have anything to do with encodings. I did stream.seek(0) before reading and it read it all right. I suspected that the problem was with encodings because usually when they're off you either get questions marks or empty strings everywhere, in this case I got an empty string.